# Get cursor from ole32.dll (4 strange bytes)

Tags: c++, winapi

Good day!

I'm trying to load this [image] cursor from "ole32.dll" to my program.

Initially I didn't know the name (index) of this cursor, so I used the [Resource Hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/) and extracted it to a file. The index was "4". And the file contained the following:

```
0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, // ICONDIR header

0x20, 0x20, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x30, 0x01,
0x00, 0x00, 0x16, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // ICONDIRENTRY header

0x28 ... // image data of the cursor itself (the size of this block is 304 bytes)
```

Then I wrote a simple code (on C#, but it doesn't matter):

```
var hmodule = LoadLibrary("ole32.dll");
var hres = FindResource(hmodule, 4, RT_CURSOR);
var size = SizeofResource(hmodule, hres);
var hcursor = LoadResource(hmodule, hres);
```

But I found that `SizeofResource` function returns **308**, not 304. And then I got the array of bytes:

```
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // 4 missed bytes
0x28 ... // data, 304 bytes
```

So my question is: what these 4 bytes mean? Is it the length of some nonexistent structure?

And the second question: in common case, how can I get the proper header of the cursor resource (particularly, the x-/y-coordinate of the hotspot and width/height of the cursor image)?

Thank you!

Comment: It is the hotspot of the cursor.  Two 16-bit values, (0, 0) makes the arrow tip at the upper-left corner the active pixel.  Very unclear why you don't simply use LoadCursor() or LoadImage(), the trivial way to get a resource converted to a HCURSOR.

Comment: @Hans Passant, sorry, I didn't notice your message earlier... Many thanks! :)

Comment: @Hans Passant, maybe you could post this answer to the main thread so I can vote it?

Comment: If only I had the faintest idea why you are trying to do this.  Cody is working with you, he ought to get you on the right track.

Answer (score 3):

> "Initially I didn't know the name (index) of this cursor, so I used the Resource Hacker and extracted it to a file."

This is the first place you went wrong. You shouldn't just extract resources out of Windows DLLs and expect to use them. If they are intended for public use, then there will be a documented mechanism to use them. If not, then you shouldn't use them. They are private and reserved for the operating system. Stealing them is almost certainly not legal; consult a lawyer.

In this case, the idea is that the cursors will be displayed automatically when you use the OLE libraries to implement drag-and-drop. When you process `IDropSource::GiveFeedback`, return the value `DRAGDROP_S_USEDEFAULTCURSORS` to…use the default cursors.

> Then I wrote a simple code…

And this is where you ***really*** went wrong. Legality aside, if you want to extract the cursors bundled with Windows to a file and include them as embedded resources in your application, then you're perfectly free to do that. But what you should *certainly* not do is try to grovel around inside of the Windows DLLs to use undocumented items. This is not just legally dubious, but technically invalid because your code is liable to stop working whenever Windows gets updated. You also run into all kinds of tricky problems like this, possibly related to padding, or just insufficiently documented implementation details. It is not really worth investigating further; this is one of those cases where when it hurts to do it, you should stop doing it.

If you absolutely insist on trying to hurt yourself, then at least do it the easy way, by calling [`LoadCursor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648391.aspx) (or `LoadImage` for more control). These helper functions take care of everything for you, including loading the proper size of the cursor for the system's current DPI settings and mapping the coordinates of the hotspot. When dealing with standard resource types, there are very few compelling reasons to find and load them manually.

```
// error-checking omitted, because we are hardcore
HMODULE hmodOle = LoadLibraryEx(TEXT("ole32.dll"), NULL, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE);
HCURSOR hCursor = LoadCursor(hmodOle, MAKEINTRESOURCE(2));
FreeLibrary(hmodOle);
```

Note also that where I checked (on both Windows Server 2003 and Windows 7), the cursor you show in the question is actually #2, not #4. Cursor #4 is the one with a shortcut overlay. Subject to change at any time, of course. Did I mention you should extract the resource and embed that file into your own executable, instead of relying on private resources in Windows DLLs?

Comment: I tried to use `LoadCursor` and `LoadImage`, but when the execution of the process comes to the line `Marshal.Copy(pointer, array, 0, size);` **AccessViolationException** is thrown (in this case, the returned handle is not null and `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()` returns `0`).
But anyway, maybe you could suggest the manual way to enumerate cursor resources in the .dll file, the way which Resource Hacker uses?

Comment: I do not understand why you are doing `Marshal.Copy` at all. These functions return a handle to a cursor (`HCURSOR`). Your P/Invoke declaration should represent that as an `IntPtr`. Pass that `IntPtr` to anything that requires an `HCURSOR`. There is never a need to copy any bits. @injector

Comment: WPF offers only one constructor - `new Cursor(stream)`. I tried to use `UnmanagedMemoryStream` but anyway I'm forced to combine the cursor's image with it's header.

Comment: @injector I feel like I am getting little bits of information from you one at a time. Nowhere in the question was `Marshal.Copy` mentioned, and nowhere in the question was WPF mentioned. That is never a good way to start; Stack Overflow is not a forum, discussion is not supposed to happen in the comments. Anyway, no, `System.Windows.Input.Cursor` has only an internal constructor that takes a cursor handle, and the Handle property is internal as well. It is not designed for Win32 interop. The stream-based constructor is designed to load a cursor from a file, either ANI or CUR.

Comment: It won't work for a handle to a cursor object in memory. That is an opaque GDI handle; the class would need to specifically support it. You will either need to jump through a massive number of hoops, like rendering the cursor to a bitmap, saving the bitmap to a cursor file, and then loading it into the `Cursor` class using the provided constructor, or you can just P/Invoke the required SDK functions to manipulate the cursor. That's what I would do. Or um...add the cursor as a resource to your WPF project, and load it the normal way, the way the Framework supports natively.

Comment: "I feel like I am getting little bits of information from you one at a time." My bad, sorry :( I got it, thanks.

Comment: Actually I got it working. I combined the image data with the header, then created `MemoryStream` and passed it to the `Cursor` constructor.